# Fastest way to find position of elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I need to identify the position inside `list` of the elements in `target`. Straightforward solution:

```
Timing[target // Map[Position[list, #] &] ;
```

> 15s

I needed a faster algorithm for my real case. Here is my try but any completely different solution is also very welcome. I assigned a score to each element, compared scores first, then look for the specific element within the candidates.

```
Timing[target // Map[identifyTerms];]
```

> 2.5s

But this is still not fast enough (in the real case)

Here my dummy example I made for this question:

```
(*list and target*)

list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} // Permutations[#, {2, 7}] & // 
    RandomSample // Map[Dot @@ # &];

target = {a, b, c, d, e, f} // Permutations[#, {2, 5}] & // 
   Map[Dot @@ # &];

(*simple target: target={a.b.c}*)
(*simple list: list={a, b.f, a.b.c}*)


(*functions*)

getScore[expr_] := 
 expr /. {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 6, g -> 7, 
    h -> 8} /. Dot -> Times

listScores = list // getScore;
identifyTerms[expr_] := Module[{cand, p},
   cand = Position[listScores, getScore[expr]] // Flatten;
   p = Position[list[[cand]], expr] // Flatten;
   cand[[p]]];
```

Comment: A solution would be to make the scores unique by changing getScore, but I cannot play around with this function since it's used in many other places... I guess I could define a completely new one

Comment: Could you give a more minimal example that's a little easier to play with?

Comment: Hi. I added a simple target and list, removed the termsID part, and changed the notation a bit. But I am not sure how to make it more minimal ... IdentifyTerms is applied to each term in target

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that this code does just `FirstPosition[list, #, {1}, Heads -> False] & /@ target`? Or alternatively `Lookup[PositionIndex[list], target]`

Comment: Yes, that does the same as my simple version, posted at the top, ```target // Map[Position[list, #] &```

Comment: In that case `Lookup[PositionIndex[list], target]` should do what you need, but much faster (basically instantaneously for me). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi. This solved my question yes. In my real case it is more complex (since each term is a sum of terms, and one cannot avoid Map); but I adapted my solutiuon creating `PositionIndex` outside identifyTerms, to do it only once, and using `Lookup`. Thank you very much for your comments!!

Comment: I could post my answer, or you promote your comment to answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the best way to solve this problem is to first use `PositionIndex` to create a hash table up front so WL doesn't have to keep doing the same thing over and over:

```
posInd = PositionIndex[list];
Lookup[posInd, target]
```

or

```
Lookup[posInd, #]& /@ target
```